# Adding an onclick event to a text without breaking the line

Tags: html

I need to add an `onclick` event (rather than a hyperlink) to a text. But using `p` tag breaks the line:

[image]

Here is the code and [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/qajeri/4/edit?html,output). Could anyone help?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    See our <p onclick="openWindow()" style="cursor: pointer; color:blue">support page</p> and other things...
    <script>
      function openWindow() {
      window.open("https://www.google.com");
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `p` is a block element, that's why it breaks the line. You can `span`, which is an inline element.

Comment: You should use `<a>` not `<span>`. It can be used for `onclick` too

Comment: I find it really hard to understand how people vote up for a span solution here... Its clearly an `<a>` situation... spans should not be clickable.... its just like advising OP to give the `<p>` an inline style. There are many ways to solve this but it should be solved correctly too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you should use `<a>`.

You can still use `onclick`. Just give it `href="#"`

```
See our <a onclick="openWindow();" href="#">support page</a> and other things...
```

1. [Semantically](http://webdesign.about.com/od/htmltags/a/why-semantic-html.htm) correct
2. Saves the styling overhead of the `<span>`
3. If you globally style `<a>` elements in your page, it will get the style too.

**Side Note**

If your only intention is to open the link in a new tab (as in your example) then use `target` instead of JS

```
See our <a target="_blank" href="https://www.google.com">support page</a> and other things...
```

Answer (score 4):

Use span

```
<span>See our <span onclick="openWindow()" style="cursor: pointer; color:blue">support page</span> and other things...</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a span inside a p tag

```
    <p>See our <span onclick="openWindow()" style="cursor: pointer; color:blue">suadpport page</span> and other things...</p>
```

Take a look at [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/yupilo/edit?html,output)

Or even better use tag a instead of a span. [Here](http://jsbin.com/demire/edit?html,output)